# Unable to add a Service Reference to a WCF service that is hosted locally

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have successfully created my service, I have modified it ever so slightly so that it does a little more than the bog standard "Hello World".

The service compiles and runs and give me the following address to add into my client application:

127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc

When I follow the next tutorial in the series:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

During step 5, when I add the reference to the service, it gives me the following error message:

An error (Details below) occurred while attempting to find services at '127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc'

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc?wsdl'.

The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.

There was an error downloading '127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc?xsd=xsd0'.

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc'.

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service 127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..

If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Are you able to browse to 127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc and 127.0.0.1:81/Appointments.svc ?wsdl from IE wihtout any problems?

Comment: Yes I can view the service fine in IE/Chrome, it shows me how to use the service from code as is described in the tutorial. This is why I don't understand why I can't add the reference to the service to a project. 

I have fresh installations of both Visual Web Developer + c# 2010 express. I don't have any unusual settings. I don't understand why it's so difficult >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it might be some permission issues. Can you try to grant permissions on  C:\Windows\Temp and see if that resolves your problem. The account that is associated with your apppool under which the service is running needs to have permissions on this folder.

Comment: I have added the following user accounts to the c:\windows\temp\

My own user account
IIS_WPG

How do i check which user my apppool is running under?


I have rebooted after adding each of these user accounts, each one has both read and write enabled.

Comment: On your app pool you would have advance settings. Open it up and then check the "Identity" property under Process Model section.

Comment: Well I have added the IUSR to the permissions but I am still left with the same errors.

Comment: Is IUSR the identity under which your app pool runs?